# ClassCastException in the method offer

Tags: java, classcastexception

Quoting from [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), in offer method:

> ClassCastException - if the specified element cannot be compared with elements currently in this priority queue according to the priority queue's ordering

How do this possible? I cannot throw classCastException in this method. Can someone throw ClassCastException with this method?

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing what kind of objects you're trying to insert into the priority queue. Post your code where you're calling this!

Comment: @BarbiePylon OP is asking in which case the exception will be thrown, refering to what is said in the documentation.

Comment: Ahh okay, in that case, the answer @Jean-FrançoisSavard provided looks good!

Answer (score 2):

Simply add some elements in the `Queue` for example `String`.

Then call the `offer` method giving in an `Integer` which is not compatible with string.

This snippet :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    PriorityQueue test = new PriorityQueue();
    test.add("test");
    test.offer(new Integer(1));
}
```

Would produce this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:656)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

---

Basically, the exception will be thrown if you offer an object which is not compatible with objects already in the queue.

Comment: I understand well. We must declare nontype queue. 
PriorityQueue test = new PriorityQueue(); not Priority<Integer>() or any type. Thank you so much, you are pro.

Comment: @HalilReis It always depend of what you want to accept. You're welcome.